# How to upload OLE/2 embedded objects in Lotus Notes?

Tags: java, file-upload, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ole

According to the documentation quote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223820/399107), documents uploaded on a Notes application are, OLE/2 embedded objects. Is it possible to upload a file as an OLE/2 embedded object using the Java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lotus Notes supports OLE/2 embedded objects in two ways.

1. The object is embedded on a form using Domino Designer, so a new object instance is created whenever a new Notes document is created using the form.  In the Java API, you can access an existing OLE/2 object using the Document.getEmbeddedObjects() property, but there is no method available to create a new OLE/2 object.
2. The object is embedded in a rich text field within a Notes Document (i.e., added by an end user or by the Notes client's 'create object in field' option on the launch tab of Form properties).  In the Java API, you can access an existing OLE/2 object using the RichTextItem.getEmbeddedObjects() propety, and you can also create new OLE/2 objects via the RichTextItem.embedObject() method -- but the appropriate OLE server program for the object type you wish to embed must be installed on the same computer where your Java code is running.